# Raspberry Pi Serialport Issue

Tags: python, c, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am trying to control a servo motor via an arduino. This Arduino should get the instructions for the motor by a raspberry pi (via serialport)

Code C Arduino:

```
#include <Servo.h>


Servo servodown;


void setup() {
  servodown.attach(8);
  Serial.begin(9600);

 

}

void loop() {
  
 if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  String receivedString = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  

  int nr = receivedString.toInt();


  if (nr >= 0 && nr <= 360) {
    Serial.print("Drehe auf ");
    Serial.println(nr, DEC);
    servodown.write(nr/2);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Digga deine Zahl ist nicht gültig");
  }
}
}
```

Code Python (Raspberry)

```
import serial
import time


print("Programm startet...")
degrees = input("Gradzahl bitte!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
        ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM1", 9600, timeout=1)
        ser.reset_input_buffer()

        while True:
                ser.write(str(degrees).encode("utf-8"))
                line = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").rstrip()
                print(line)
                time.sleep(1)
```

Every Time i run the code i´m getting an error because the ttyACM1 isn´t founded.
It´s named ttyACM0 now. So i change the name in the code. Same error... Now it´s named ttyACM1.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    ser.write(str(degrees).encode("utf-8"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 571, in write
    raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

or sometimes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Connection is stable, changing cable, restarting, updating python, using sudo etc.....

Comment: You need to check the name of the serial port. Handle exceptions too

Comment: Your hardware connections are suspect. You haven't clearly identified what device you're using on the Arduino for the "*serialport*". On the RPi end, the **/dev/ttyACM1** would refer to a USB connection using CDC ACM to emulate a serial link. "*Connection is stable*" - What's does this mean?

Comment: How exactly devices are connected in hardware? What arduino model do you use? Is it based on Atmega32U and you connect it as USB device? Speculation: when python library opens a serial port, it pulls DTR line which is reset command for arduino.

Comment: I´m using the Arduion uno r4 and the rpi 400. I checked the name of the seriell port but it is always switching between ACM1 and ACM0.

Comment: How devices are connected in hardware? Are they connected with USB cable? ttyACMn looks like CDC ACM device created by arduino's USB gadget stack. If arduino restarts after opening this port on RPi, gadget stack is re-initialized, so RPi detects new device and assigns next available index to it, and old device disappears.